# How does Facebook prevent triggering automatic clicks on Like buttons?

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe

The way I see it, every user event that is relayed to the browser can also be raised programmatically. You can trigger `click`, `mouseover`, or really, pretty much *anything* sane:

```
document.getElementById('mylink').click();
document.getElementById('mylink').dispatchEvent('mouseover');
```

I know that most social networks - Facebook included - serve their  <s>cookie-dispensers</s>  social plugins through within `iframe` elements that are placed via JavaScript. But what's stopping anyone from triggering an event into that iFrame?

```
document.getElementById('myframe').contentDocument.getElementById('likebtn').click();
```

I've found multiple articles that suggest an approach by intercepting clicks (that is, when you click *anywhere* on the page, you actually click the like button), but none of them detail or examine a way where the click is raised programmatically.

- http://geekhmer.github.io/blog/2013/10/02/facebook-fan-page-auto-like/
- http://www.makingdifferent.com/automatically-increase-facebook-fans-using-javascript/

If there is a defense mechanism in place that prevents artifical click events from actually registering on elements, what's stopping anyone from modifying the frame contents with a script, or by relaying through a webserver (though the latter might be complicated due to separate authentication and HTTPS)?

---

*Disclaimer: I do not - in any way - seek for a concrete solution that accomplishes this task. I understand and fully support that this - as well as click intercepting - would be a rude, forcing, and horrible behaviour even for Voldemort to pull off. It is one's last mortyfing and pathetic attempt at gaining more publicity before failing mercillesly. I'm merely interested in the behind-the-curtain workings.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They rely on [cross domain browser policies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

```
document.getElementById('myframe').contentDocument
```

Is not accessible because the contentDocument is on another domain (facebook). There is no way you can trigger a click programmatically.

```js
document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Answer (score 2):

> But what's stopping anyone from triggering an event into that iFrame?

iframes are subject to the same-origin policy and thus can only be accessed by the parent if it is served from the same domain.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

---

Put differently: Facebook (or any other service) doesn't do anything in particular, the security is built into the HTML/DOM/browser.